# Onesignal : included_segments must be an array of strings

Tags: php, http, onesignal

I want to send push notification via API on PHP project.

This is the basic code that I use

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/',
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization'=> 'Basic '. config('onesignal.rest_api_key'),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
             ]]);

$response = $client->post('notifications', [
                    'form_params'=>[
                        'app_id' => config('onesignal.app_id'),
                        'included_segments' => ['All'],
                        'contents' => ["en"=> "Un nouveau cas de suspect vient d'être confirmé à Kinshasa"]
                    ]]) ;
```

When I execute it, `$response->getBody()->getContents()` return this

> {"errors":["included_segments must be an array of strings"]}

I don't know What is mean by `Array of string`

Comment: I see you asked this 3 months ago but I just stuck on same issue. Same problem here :(

Comment: I already resolved it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So stupid that this can be, the problem was resolved by using an other HTTP client library than Guzzle.

I don't know why but I've used https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class and with the same logique, I resolved my problem !

Hope that it'll help someone !

Comment: You are right. I solved this yesterday same way - by using simple `curl` call instead of using Guzzle

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien I don't know. I haven't gone too far on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you externalUserId OR externalUserId array is in a String formart (not integer).
e.g, 1 use "1" or '1'
instead of [1,2,3,4,5], use ['1','2','3','4','5']